# "Upright he held it, lords, that held it last", meaning?

Tags: meaning, shakespeare

In Shakespeare's Titus Andronicus when asked to become emperor Titus refuses answering that the *sceptre to control the world* (i.e., power) "upright he held it, lords, that held it last".

What is the meaning of this last sentence?

Comment: What exactly is giving you a problem with the sentence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last guy that held that sceptre held it upright? So, in the right way.

The last guy to be emperor was doing a good job, and Titus doesn't think he can do such a good job.

Comment: Now it makes indeed more sense. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could re-write it as "he that held it last held it upright, lords."